# I/O error while accessing file:/dbfs/my_hyper.hyper: SIGBUS

Tags: python, databricks, azure-databricks, hyper-api

I'm trying to write Tableau's `.hyper` file to a directory in Databricks.

However it yields

```
The database "hyper.file:/dbfs/my_hyper.hyper" could not be created: I/O error while accessing file:/dbfs/my_hyper.hyper: SIGBUS
```

Why is this happening?
I face no issues at all when writing other file types but this issue persists with `.hyper` files.

Is this a permissions issue or a bug?

*Please Advise*

*I'd be happy to provide additional info*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably this happens because DBFS doesn't support random writes (see [docs for the list of limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations)). The workaround would be to write to the local disk, like, `/tmp/`, and then copy/move files using `dbutils.fs.cp` or `dbutils.fs.mv` commands (see docs)

Comment: Thanks! I already figured that the write to `/tmp/`  and other similar locations is supported. The copy and move commands you specified look useful!